# jQuery on an external HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found similar questions but none of their answers solved my problem. My main HTML file load a script `init.js` with `<script src="js/init.js"/>` and this script is responsible of the dynamic creation of some parts of my HTML page. At some point in the script, I find the line

```
var x = jQuery('.class-site-name'), site_name = (x.length > 0 ? x.html() : '');
```

which sets the variable `site_name`. What I would like to do is to separate a portion of my main HTML file (to use as a common file), but the problem I have is that the element with class `class-site-name` would go in the external HTML file.

My question is: how can I replace the part of my `init.js` script in order to obtain the same result as before? I am looking for some instructions that tells to `init.js` to parse the external file, but with no success.

**Edit to provide more info**

My HTML file looks like:

```
<body>
  <!-- PORTION TO EXTRACT: begin -->
  <h1><a class="class-site-name">My website</a></h1>
  <nav id="nav" class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- PORTION TO EXTRACT: end -->
  <div> Text here </div>
</body>
```

I would like to separate the indicated portion into the file `menu.html` and then add to the head of the main HTML these lines:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $("#menu").load("./menu.html");
   });
</script>
```

What I first tried was to do was something like:

```
<script>
var site_name = '';
$(document).ready(
    function (){
    $("#menu").load("./menu.html", function () {
        var x = jQuery('.class-site-name');
        site_name = (x.length > 0 ? x.html() : '');
        console.log('INSIDE '+site_name);
    });
    });
console.log('OUTSIDE '+site_name);
</script>
```

but this didn't work because the variable `site_name` is not available where I put the `OUTSIDE` console log. If I had the variable filled there, I would have solved my problem. This is why I changed strategy and I tried to do the work directly in my `init.js` script.

Comment: Hi @AlessioDV. To me it's not enough info to understand the problem. Please explain what and how you divide your HTML to external. And how you load this external HTML.

Comment: I really tried, but also don't understand what is being asked here. Do you want to load another js file using javascript (not possible). What external file are you trying to load? Note that for loading external files, you'd need to run a local webserver, due to the CORS policy.

Comment: What you can do is, you can make init.js part of the common html file, you are going to create or atleast the part of init.js depends on new common html file elements.

Comment: @Benny I just edited my question to provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: @Papooch See my edits for more info, they should answer the doubts. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Well, the obvious question is why would you want to extract the site name from the html, it seems bit unnecessary to me. Your problem is that you are calling the function on document.ready, but you should only call it only after you have loaded the menu.

Comment: @Papooch You are absolutely right for the site_name, there is no reason to separate it. I need to do an analogous thing doing a jQuery for "class-nav a" (the portion with the list), but I posted the question asking for site_name to have a simpler thing to ask.

Comment: Your approach is still a bit strange: You build the website with blocks and then extract information from said blocks. I'd suggest having the information available at build time and then use it to build the blocks. E.g. have site_name stored in a variable somewhere and then build the content programatically using these variables instead. Seeing as you are using jQuery, you would highly benefit from this in the long run.

Comment: But to your problem (now that I have actually understood): you should wrap the whole code in $("document").ready. The console.log statement at the end gets executed _before_ the ready function. If you put it at the end of the ready function, you will see that it works as expected.

Comment: This is what I understood after my first attempt: indeed in the console I first see the "OUTSIDE" console.log statement (with empty site_name) and then the "INSIDE" console.log statement with site_name properly filled. But the problem I still have is that the variable site_name (and others depending on the list in my menu.html file) is needed by the init.js script. Ultimately, I don't know how to let the loaded part and the init.js script communicate.